# Динамическое создание формы c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, структуры-данных

Задача приложения: принимать запросы пользователей, и в зависимости от выбранного типа запроса выводить определенный набор полей для заполнения.

Для начала я создал такие классы:

```
    public class Request {
        public ICollection<RequestField> Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestField {
        public Request Request { get; set; }
        public RequestTypeField FieldType { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestTypeField {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestType {
        public ICollection<RequestTypeField> Fields { get; set; }
    }
```

**RequestType** содержит список необходимых полей и их названия, сам **Request** содержит список этих полей со значениями. Работает отлично, если поля всегда содержат строковые значения.

Далее задача усложнилась, нужно хранить не только строковые значения, но и числовые, дату и т.д. Модифицировал класс RequestTypeField:

```
public class RequestTypeField {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
    public FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
}

public enum FieldType { Строка, Число, Дата }
```

Добавил перечисление, для указания типа поля, но продолжаю все хранить в string, чтобы конвертировать в нужное значение.

Дальше понадобилось сделать некоторые поля с выпадающим списком:

```
    public class RequestTypeField {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
        public FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; } 
    }
    public enum FieldType { Строка, Число, Дата, Список }
```

В поле DefaultValue храню строку вида "value1;value2;value3" - все опции выпадающего списка через знак ";". Обращаюсь к этому полю только если

> FieldType == FieldType.Список

Как видим, чем дальше - тем колхознее решения.

В данный момент стоит задача добавить возможность вводить данные таблично. К примеру:

- Имя - Строка
- Возраст - Число
- Места работы - Таблица из 2 колонок: даты и места

Единственный вариант, который приходит на ум - положить в **DefaultValue** строку вида "column1;column2;column3". Но сложить эти значения в **Request.Fields** уже не получается. Как быть? Есть ли какой-то паттерн, как делать правильно динамические формы?

Comment: Так а нафиг всё в 1 класс загонять и костыли наращивать? Заведите отдельный класс под каждый вид запроса.

Comment: @yolosora Виды запроса тоже заводятся пользователями. И их уже сейчас 2000+, такое количество таблиц не вариант создавать

Comment: @Bulson asp.net

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев очень_странная_система

Answer (score 1):

> Задача приложения: принимать запросы пользователей, и в зависимости от выбранного типа запроса выводить определенный набор полей для заполнения.

Ваш вопрос, кстати, очень интересный и достаточно сложный, но почему-то у здешней публики он не вызвал должного отклика. А между тем, наверняка каждый программист с подобной проблемой встречался или встретится в будущем обязательно.

Проблему эту можно кратко обозначить как **проверка объектов на динамические условия или правила**.

Возьмем для примера такой класс фильма

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }        
    public int? Length { get; set; }
}
```

Как обычно статически проверяют такой класс? Вероятно так

```
public bool IsValid(Movie movie)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
    {
         return false;
    }
    if (movie.Length < 60 || movie.Length > 240)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (movie.ReleaseDate.Value.Year < 1903)
    {
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Если вспомнить про делегаты и LINQ, то эту же задачу можно решить так

```
public bool IsValid1(Movie movie)
{
    Func<Movie, bool>[] rules =
    {
        m => String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Title),
        m => m.Length < 60 || m.Length > 240,
        m => m.ReleaseDate.Value.Year < 1903
    };

    return rules.All(rule => rule(movie) == false);
}
```

Если же нам нужно проверять свойства фильма динамически и в зависимости от результатов делать вывод тех или иных контролов, а затем снова делать вывод, вот тогда возникают некоторые сложности...
Вот как здесь
[image: пример]
Пользователь ввел название фильма? Тогда отображаем поле для ввода длительности фильма. Если длительность фильма равна 75, то говорим, что все хорошо. Однако, если длительность фильма равна 100, то отображаем поле для ввода даты.
И это только для одного объекта. А если таких объектов несколько? Как быть?

Восемь лет назад Scott Allen сделал курс [LINQ Architecture](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/linq-architecture) и там можно найти пример решения данной проблемы. Графически схему решения можно представить так
[image: схема решения]

*Shape*(форма) или состояние проверяемого объекта связана с другими *Shape* через *Arrow*(стрелка) имеет ассоциированное с ней *Rule*(правило). Когда проверяемый объект достигает определенного состояния, и если это состояние связано со следующим состоянием, то мы применяем к объекту следующее проверочное правило, и если правило вернуло `true`, то действуем так пока не достигнем конечной формы.

Начнем с класса Стрелки

```
public class Arrow<TData>
{
    //название ассоциированной Shape
    public string PointsTo { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    //ассоциированное правило
    public Func<TData, bool> Rule { get; set; } = _ => false;
}
```

Это класс Формы(состояния)

```
public class Shape<TData, TResult>
{
    public Shape()
    {
        Arrows = new List<Arrow<TData>>();
        Result = default(TResult);
    }

    public TResult Result { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //через это свойство мы будем определять нужный нам контрол в UI 
    public PropertySpecifier<TData> RequiredField { get; set; }
    //связь со стрелками
    public List<Arrow<TData>> Arrows { get; set; }
}
```

…

```
//класс определителя свойства по выражению
public class PropertySpecifier<T>
{
    //извлечение из выражения названия свойства целевого объекта
    public PropertySpecifier(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        if(expression.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            var me = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            _propertyName = me.Member.Name; 
        }
        else if(expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var ue = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
            var me = ue.Operand as MemberExpression;
            _propertyName = me.Member.Name;
        }

    }

    private string _propertyName;
    public string PropertyName => _propertyName;

    public static IEqualityComparer<PropertySpecifier<T>> Comparer
    {
        get
        {
            return new _Comparer();
        }
    }

    private class _Comparer : IEqualityComparer<PropertySpecifier<T>>
    {
        public bool Equals(PropertySpecifier<T> x, PropertySpecifier<T> y)
        {
            return x.PropertyName.Equals(y.PropertyName);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(PropertySpecifier<T> obj)
        {
            return obj.PropertyName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PropertyName;
    }
}
```

Класс Схемы

```
public class Flowchart<TData, TResult>
{
    public Flowchart()
    {
        Shapes = new List<Shape<TData, TResult>>();
    }

    //проверка схемы
    public void Validate()
    {
        CheckForInvalidDestinations();
        CheckForDuplicateNames();
    }

    //Оценка типа
    public EvaluationResults<TData, TResult> Evaluate(TData data)
    {
        var currentShape = Shapes[0];
        var visitedShapes = new List<Shape<TData, TResult>> { currentShape };
        var currentArrow = currentShape.Arrows.FirstOrDefault(arrow => arrow.Rule(data));

        while (currentArrow != null)
        {
            currentShape = Shapes.Where(shape => shape.Name.Equals(currentArrow.PointsTo)).Single();
            visitedShapes.Add(currentShape);
            currentArrow = currentShape.Arrows.FirstOrDefault(arrow => arrow.Rule(data));
        }

        return ComputeEvaluationResults(visitedShapes);
    }

    //Вычисление результатов оценки типа
    private EvaluationResults<TData, TResult> ComputeEvaluationResults(List<Shape<TData, TResult>> visitedShapes)
    {
        var results = new EvaluationResults<TData, TResult>();
        var lastShape = visitedShapes[visitedShapes.Count - 1];
        results.Result = lastShape.Result;
        results.RequiredFields = visitedShapes.Where(s => s.RequiredField != null)
                                              .Select(s => s.RequiredField)
                                              .Distinct(PropertySpecifier<TData>.Comparer)
                                              .ToList();
        return results;
    }

    //проверка названий Форм(состояний)
    public List<Shape<TData, TResult>> Shapes { get; set; }

    private void CheckForDuplicateNames()
    {
        var duplicateShapes = Shapes.GroupBy(s => s.Name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        if (duplicateShapes.Count() > 0)
        {
            string message = "Названия состояний повторяются: " +
                             duplicateShapes.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append(s.Key + " "), sb => sb.ToString());

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }
    }

    //проверка целевых Форм(состояний)
    private void CheckForInvalidDestinations()
    {
        var names = Shapes.Select(s => s.Name);
        var problemTransitions = Shapes.SelectMany(s => s.Arrows)
                                       .Where(t => !names.Contains(t.PointsTo));
        if (problemTransitions.Count() > 0)
        {
            string message = "Следующие целевые названия состояний ошибочны: " +
                problemTransitions.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, t) => sb.Append(t.PointsTo + " "), sb => sb.ToString());

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

…

```
//класс Результата
public class EvaluationResults<T, R>
{
    public R Result { get; set; }
    public List<PropertySpecifier<T>> RequiredFields { get; set; }
}
```

Подсобный класс для удобства

```
//подсобный класс расширяющих методов для работы с создаваемыми правилами по шаблону FluentAPI
public static class FluentFlowchartExtensions
{
    //Добавить Форму(состояние)
    public static Flowchart<T, R> AddShape<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart, string shapeName)
    {
        var shape = new Shape<T, R> { Name = shapeName };
        chart.Shapes.Add(shape);
        return chart;
    }

    //Определение Результата для нужной Формы
    public static Flowchart<T, R> YieldsResult<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart, R result)
    {
        chart.LastShape().Result = result;
        return chart;
    }

    //Определение привязки к свойству целевого объекта через выражение
    public static Flowchart<T, R> Requires<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart, Expression<Func<T, object>> field)
    {
        var specifier = new PropertySpecifier<T>(field);
        chart.LastShape().RequiredField = specifier;
        return chart;
    }

    //Создание Стрелки
    public static Flowchart<T, R> WithArrowPointingTo<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart, string pointsTo)
    {
        var arrow = new Arrow<T> {PointsTo = pointsTo};
        chart.LastShape().Arrows.Add(arrow);
        return chart;
    }

    //Добавить правило
    public static Flowchart<T, R> AndRule<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart, Func<T, bool> rule)
    {
        chart.LastShape().LastArrow().Rule = rule;
        return chart;
    }

    //извлечение последней Формы
    public static Shape<T, R> LastShape<T, R>(this Flowchart<T, R> chart)
    {
        return chart.Shapes[chart.Shapes.Count - 1];
    }

    //извлечение последней Стрелки
    public static Arrow<T> LastArrow<T, R>(this Shape<T, R> shape)
    {
        return shape.Arrows[shape.Arrows.Count - 1];
    }
}
```

Это всё. Всё пока лишь было абстракцией. Перейдем к конкретике. 
Результаты будем определять с помощью `enum`

```
public enum MovieResult
{
    NotEnoughInformation, 
    GoodMovie,
    BadMovie
}
```

И вот он, ради него все это было написано :)

```
public class MovieFlowchart : Flowchart<Movie, MovieResult>
{
    //--Правила для фильма
    //название фильма не должно быть пустым
    Func<Movie, bool> _titleNotNullOrEmpty = m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Title);
    //продолжительность фильма слишком велика
    Func<Movie, bool> _lengthIsTooLong = m => m.Length > 240;
    //продолжительность фильма в самый раз
    Func<Movie, bool> _lengthIsJustRight = m => m.Length == 75;
    //продолжительность фильма указана
    Func<Movie, bool> _lengthExists = m => m.Length.HasValue;
    //фильм слишком старый
    Func<Movie, bool> _tooOld = m => m.ReleaseDate.HasValue &&
                                    m.ReleaseDate.Value.Year < 2000;
    //дата выхода указана
    Func<Movie, bool> _hasReleaseDate = m => m.ReleaseDate.HasValue;

    //ctor
    public MovieFlowchart()
    {
        var chart = this;

        //формируем схему для фильма
        chart.AddShape("CheckTitle")
                .Requires(m => m.Title)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("CheckLength").AndRule(_titleNotNullOrEmpty)

            .AddShape("CheckLength")
                .Requires(m => m.Length)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("BadMovie").AndRule(_lengthIsTooLong)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("GoodMovie").AndRule(_lengthIsJustRight)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("CheckReleaseDate").AndRule(_lengthExists)

            .AddShape("CheckReleaseDate")
                .Requires(m => m.ReleaseDate)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("BadMovie").AndRule(_tooOld)
                .WithArrowPointingTo("GoodMovie").AndRule(_hasReleaseDate)

            .AddShape("BadMovie").YieldsResult(MovieResult.BadMovie)
            .AddShape("GoodMovie").YieldsResult(MovieResult.GoodMovie);
    }
}
```

Как с этим работать? Да, хоть так через тесты

```
[TestClass]
public class MovieEvaluationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MovieWithoutATitleNeedsMoreInformation()
    {
        var chart = new MovieFlowchart();
        var movie = new Movie { Title = String.Empty };

        var result = chart.Evaluate(movie).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(MovieResult.NotEnoughInformation, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MovieWithTitleAndLength75IsGood()
    {
        var chart = new MovieFlowchart();
        var movie = new Movie { Title = "Foobar", Length = 75 };

        var result = chart.Evaluate(movie).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(MovieResult.GoodMovie, result);
    }
}
```

Вы еще не устали? Тогда кратко про работу в приложении. Вот контроллер так выглядит

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new HomeIndexViewModel();
        vm.Movie = new Movie();
        vm.Message = "Введите название фильма";
        vm.RequiredNames.Clear();
        vm.RequiredNames.Add("Title");

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(HomeIndexViewModel vm)
    {
        //проверяем фильм
        var flowchart = new MovieFlowchart();
        EvaluationResults<Movie, MovieResult> result = flowchart.Evaluate(vm.Movie);

        switch (result.Result)
        {
            case MovieResult.NotEnoughInformation:
                vm.Message = "Надо больше данных!";
                break;
            case MovieResult.GoodMovie:
                vm.Message = "Хороший фильм.";
                break;
            case MovieResult.BadMovie:
                vm.Message = "Это какой-то неправильный фильм.";
                break;
        }

        //запоминаем названия нужных свойств
        vm.RequiredNames.Clear();
        vm.RequiredNames.AddRange(result.RequiredFields.Select(f => f.PropertyName));

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Скот в своем примере выводил Json, а потом через javascript отображал нужные поля и сообщения. Я же создал кастомный тегхелпер

```
[HtmlTargetElement("movie")]
public class MovieTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("view-model")]
    public HomeIndexViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        string preContent = $@"<h3>{ViewModel.Message}</h3>
                              <form action='/' method='post'>";
        string postContent = @"<p>
                                <input id='submitMovie' type='submit' value='Создать' />
                               </p>
                              </form>";

        //составляем список нужных свойств фильма
        var props = from prop in typeof(Movie).GetProperties()
                    from name in ViewModel.RequiredNames
                    where prop.Name == name
                    select prop;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            //извлекаем значение свойства
            var value = prop.GetValue(ViewModel.Movie);

            builder.AppendLine("<p>");
            builder.AppendLine($"<label for='Movie_{prop.Name}'>{prop.Name}</label>");
            builder.AppendLine($"<input id='Movie_{prop.Name}' name='Movie.{prop.Name}' type='text' value='{value?.ToString()}' />");
            builder.AppendLine($"<span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='Movie.{prop.Name}' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>");
            builder.AppendLine("</p>");
        }

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(builder.ToString());

        output.TagName = "div";
        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent(preContent);
        output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent(postContent);
    }
}
```

Вьюшка получается такая

```html
@model HomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Фильм";
}

<h2>Фильм</h2>

<movie view-model="@Model"></movie>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index")
</div>
```

Вот теперь всё! Пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/6Q8YVmq63XMpM5)